# Images not appearing on the same line with display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

In order to position two images beside each other (i.e. the two images are on the same line), I tried the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        #container {
            width:100%;
        }

        img {
            display:inline-block;
            width:50%;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center"><strong>Test</strong></h1>
    <div id="container">
        <img src="Google-logo.png">
        <img src="Google-logo.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

The width of the container div **should** be shared equally by the two images, right? However, this does not happen and the images appear on two separate lines.

If, however, I use float:left instead, the images do appear on the same line. Why is this?

Comment: This is because inline-block add extra space between the elements, please have a read in this article https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Using float the image appear on the same lane because they exit from the page flux(like absolute position), going on the left respect to the other img . Have you tried to change your "container" to inline-block. Try it pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the new line between the `img` tags:

```
<div>
    <img src="..." alt=""><img src="..." alt="">
</div>
```

This happens because elements which are declared with `inline` or `inline-block` are sensitive to whitespace.

More information: [on David Walsh's Blog](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Commonly layouts are done with floats or flexbox instead.

**Floats**

```css
/* Clearfix */
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
}

.item-1 {
  background: red;  
}

.item-2 {
  background: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <div class="item item-2"></div>
</div>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  flex: 1; /* Or use width: 50%; */
  height: 100px;
}

.item-1 {
  background: red;  
}

.item-2 {
  background: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <div class="item item-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried removing the whitespace and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
#container {
            max-width:100%;
            display:flex;
        }

        img {
            flex:1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use css [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) property:

```
  img {
        width:50%;
        float:left;
    }
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmjwj2dq/) . no need of display.

Answer (score 0):

Give `align property` to images.

```
 <img src="Google-logo.png" align="left">
 <img src="Google-logo.png" align="left">
```

`https://jsfiddle.net/bt2341yh/`

Answer (score 0):

According to the above solution it is very difficult to keep the page next to next line content. It will looks like minified version of our code. So try to add `font-size:0` on your parent element `#container`. This will resolve this issue.

```
#container { 
   width:100%;
   font-size:0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nt4wzqzg/)

Answer (score 0):

Images give margins and padding so giving 50% width wont bring them in a line. Try reducing their widths or add `float:left`.

```
img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```